# Linux mail client which works with GMail and can use vim as editor

Tags: linux, vim, gmail, email-client

I'm forced to use GMail and would like to write my emails using vim on a Ubuntu 13.10 system. Looks like mutt would be my best (and only?) choice, but I'm not sure about it's status and how it works in day to day work, if you have to interact with people using GMail to write HTML mails. Any recomendations?

Comment: So, to rewrite your question: An email client which supports sending mails as HTML and you want to use vim as an editor?

Comment: Yes, I want to use vim as editor. I don't need to write HTML mails, but I have to read them. I'm aware of the problems, so I don't expect the html to go away in some magical way. Just asking for other users experience and some helpful formatting / higlighting would be nice.

Comment: There is at least one Firefox add-in that allows you to edit any Firefox text field in Vim, but I can't think of the name of it (or find it in Google) right now. Similar things might exist for other browsers. I don't know, though, if Gmail's editor window is too fancy for that (nor even if you actually want to use a web browser at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutt should work fine. GMail supports both POP3 and IMAP, but recommends the latter. There are a lot of options available when building mutt. [Mutt can work with IMAP](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/UseIMAP), if support for it is compiled in.

With regard to viewing HTML mail in mutt, I have the following in my  `~/.muttrc`:

```
alternative_order text/html text/plain text/enriched
auto_view text/html
```

And in `~/.mailcap`:

```
text/html; links -html-margin 1 -width 100  -html-numbered-links 1 -dump %s; copiousoutput
```

This generally gives a nice text rendering (without pictures of course) of the HTML. This setup uses the text-based [links](http://links.twibright.com/) web browser. But you could use e.g. [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) or [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Clawsmail works with every IMAP and POP3 Server (afaik) and has an option to specify the editor being used. I'm not sure though if it works with just vim or if you need gvim.

Answer (score 0):

Pine or Alpine can also be used with vim as editor. And if I remember correctly, Alpine is easier to configure than mutt. It depends on what you want.